# JavaFX + Spring: возможно ли избежать жесткого связывания главного приложения и контроллера?

Tags: java, spring, javafx

В данном [учебном примере](https://code.makery.ch/ru/library/javafx-tutorial/part2/) предлагается создать тестовые данные прямо в главном классе приложения, а также вызывать из него метод JavaFX-контроллера `setMainApp(MainApp mainApp)`, который даст доступ к данным `personData`. Другими словами, контроллер и главный класс приложения жёстко связаны.

Приведённый ниже код пока что НЕ мой:

**MainApp.java**

```java
public class MainApp extends Application {

  private Stage primaryStage;
  private BorderPane rootLayout;

  private ObservableList<Person> personData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

  public MainApp() {
    personData.add(new Person("Hans", "Muster"));
    personData.add(new Person("Ruth", "Mueller"));
    // ... и другие
  }


  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

    initRootLayout();
    showPersonOverview();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  // ...

  public void showPersonOverview() {
    try {

      // Загружаем сведения об адресатах.
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
      loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
      AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

      // Помещаем сведения об адресатах в центр корневого макета.
      rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);

      // Даём контроллеру доступ к главному приложению.
      PersonOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
      controller.setMainApp(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /** Возвращает данные в виде наблюдаемого списка адресатов. */
  public ObservableList<Person> getPersonData() {
      return personData;
  }
}
```

**PersonOverviewController.java**

```java
public class PersonOverviewController {

  // ...
  // Ссылка на главное приложение.
  private MainApp mainApp;

  public PersonOverviewController() {}

  /**
   * Инициализация класса-контроллера. Этот метод вызывается автоматически
   * после того, как fxml-файл будет загружен.
   */
  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
      // Инициализация таблицы адресатов с двумя столбцами.
      firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
      lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
  }

  /** Вызывается главным приложением, которое даёт на себя ссылку. */
  public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
      this.mainApp = mainApp;
      // Добавление в таблицу данных из наблюдаемого списка
      personTable.setItems(mainApp.getPersonData());
  }
}
```

Модифицируя данное учебное приложение, я решил получать данные не из главного класса, из Spring-бина `PeopleRepository`:

```java
public class PeopleRepository implements IPeopleRepository {

  public ObservableList<Person> getPeople() {

    ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    people.add(new Person( "Muster", "Hans"));
    people.add(new Person("Mueller", "Ruth"));
    // ... и другие

    return people;
  }
}
```

Я не знаю, зачем ещё кроме данных нам нужен доступ к главному классу приложения, но теперь, когда мы можем получить данные из бина, `setMainApp` нам вроде как больше не нужен. Исходя из того, что мы загружаем FXML с помощью `FXMLLoader` в главном классе приложения, связь между главным классом приложения и View есть, а во View есть ссылка на соответствующие контроллеры. На основе этой логики, я упростил `PersonOverviewController` следующим образом:

```java
public class PersonOverviewController {

  @FXML
  private TableView<Person> peopleTable;
  @FXML
  private TableColumn<Person, String> familyNameColumn;
  @FXML
  private TableColumn<Person, String> givenNameColumn;

  @FXML
  private Label familyNameLabel;
  @FXML
  // ... и другие компоненты


  public PersonOverviewController() {}

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
    IPeopleRepository peopleRepository = (PeopleRepository) applicationContext.getBean("PeopleRepository");

    familyNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().familyNameProperty());
    givenNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().givenNameProperty());

    peopleTable.setItems(peopleRepository.getPeople());
  }
}
```

Хотя приложение собирается Maven-ом без ошибок, метод `initialize()` просто-напросто не вызывается (`System.out.println("test");` в данном метода не выполняется). Естественно, в таблице никаких данных нет. Что я сделал неправильно?

Полный листинг главного класса приложения:

```java
public class MainApp extends javafx.application.Application {

  private Stage primaryStage;
  private BorderPane rootLayout;

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    launch();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX тест");

    initializeRootLayout();
    showPersonOverview();
  }


  private void initializeRootLayout() {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml"));

    try {

      rootLayout = loader.load();

      Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void showPersonOverview() {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/PersonOverview.fxml"));

    try {
      AnchorPane personOverview = loader.load();
      rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `@FXML void initialize()` вызывает `loader.load()`. Покажите что у вас осталось в `App.java`. В целом по тексту все верно. Возможно обращением в App за данными в примере хотели показать в целом как получить дочерний контроллер. Такой подход практикуется между parent/child stage, а для mainStage оно выглядит странновато.

Comment: @Maxim, благодарю Вас за комментарий и за то, что прочитали этот вопрос. Добавил в конец вопроса полный листинг класса `App`. Я убрал из него метод `getPrimaryStage`, потому что он нигде явно не вызывается, а по результатам эксперимента - его наличие ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Проверьте `sout` перед и после `personOverview = loader.load()`.

Comment: @Maxim, пока всё нормально. И перед `AnchorPane personOverview = loader.load();` sout выводится, и сразу после. И вообще, метод отрабатывает до конца, доказательством чего является хоть и пустая, но отображающаяся таблица адресатов, которую предложено сделать в туториале.

Comment: не вникая в это все, могу сказать, что `public class MainApp` не может находится в файле `App.java`. Ну никак

Comment: Если load() вызывается, а до метода initialize() дело не доходит и не выводит ошибок, у меня идей нет.Разве что наугад обернуть `showPersonOverview` в `new Thread{Platform.runLater()}`

Comment: @michael_best, в реальном приложении класс и файл вообще по-другому называются, но я в этом вопросе назвал как все привыкли (и ошибся).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понял до конца, в чём дело, но всё разрешилось, когда я изменил способ поиска шаблонов.

В туториале изначально был предложен такой способ поиска шаблонов:

```
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
```

В JavaFX 11 это не работает. Кроме того,

> Создайте новый класс внутри пакета view и назовите его
>   PersonOverviewController.java. (Мы должны разместить этот
>   класс-контроллер в том же пакете, где находится файл разметки
>   PersonOverview.fxml, иначе Scene Builder не сможет его найти.

тоже нынче не актуально. Рабочим же является это решение ([ссылка на англоязычный оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19603055/4818123)):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/main.fxml"));
Parent content = loader.load();
```

Шаблон main.fxml будет найден, если его положить в папку `src/main/resources`. После того, как я это сделал, основная проблема данного вопроса была также решена.